# Libraries to calculate kinematics using Screw Theory

Tags: kinematics, product-of-exponentials, screw-theory

Most kinematics libraries/packages use the conventional transformation matrices (DH parameters). However, I'm looking for something that uses Screw Theory principles to set up the Product of Exponentials formula.

For eg., the KDL library from Orocos uses homogeneous transformation matrices, quaternions, Euler angles, etc. under the hood. But are there libraries that make use of twists and exponentials to derive the kinematics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lynch and Park's *Modern Robotics* book uses the product of exponentials formula and screw axes to describe manipulators, and they have a well-documented library available in Python, MATLAB, and Mathematica. Plus there is a community-released C++ port using CMake/Eigen.

- Book is available on this site (for free): http://modernrobotics.org/
- Original library is here: https://github.com/NxRLab/ModernRobotics
- C++ port is here: https://github.com/Le0nX/ModernRoboticsCpp

Full disclosure: I contributed some small elements to the book, and helped organize, build-out, and maintain the software library.

Answer (score 0):

While Screw theory has only been explored and deployed in robotics in research and academic capacity, I found this library on github that could help you.

[Screw-Theory-Toolbox-for-Robotics-ST24R](https://github.com/DrPardosGotor/Screw-Theory-Toolbox-for-Robotics-ST24R)

I hope you find this useful.